# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INFmodule_debug.kotlin_module' in Android studio 4.0

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, android-studio-4.0

Recently I have updated android studio to `4.0`. After updating I am seeing this error when trying to build the project. 
It's not frequent but still showing time to time when change something and build again the project.

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/module_debug.kotlin_module'
```

I also added below line in my project `build.gradle` file in packaging options as mentioned in some other questions but still its not working:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'
}
```

Anyone else is facing this issue if so how did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The mentioned workaround should work. If not, then make sure you are applying it to the affected module gradle file.